# Как изменить Background у Status Bar?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Есть простая область с Navigation Bar вверху, а после него растянутый Table View.

Navigation Bar покрасил в некоторый RGB цвет и теперь есть необходимость покрасить в этот же цвет область выше него - Status Bar.

В файле `AppDelegate.swift` в `application` я добавил эту строку:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: CGFloat(7), green: CGFloat(14), blue: CGFloat(30), alpha: CGFloat(1))
```

И в самом низу расширил `UIApplication`:

```
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }
}
```

Не работает. Но если `UIColor.init()` заменить, например, на `.red`, то Status Bar станет красным цветом.

Почему не работает `UIColor.init()` и как мне установить свой RGB цвет в Status Bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает, потому что (как сообщает Xcode) "UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range", т.е. значения компонент цвета выходят за пределы допустимых. Максимально возможное значение компоненты цвета - 1.0. Таким образом, вам нужно разделить значение каждой компоненты на 255.0, вот так:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: CGFloat(7 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(14 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(30 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1))
```